# bootstrap Font Awesome icon for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Is there a Font Awesome icon for Javascript? Like "fa-html5" for HTML5.

```
<i class="fa fa-html5 " aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: If it doesn't exist, [request it on GitHub](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=javascript). These kind of questions don't belong to SO.

Comment: @AdamAzad why not?

Comment: @minseong ["Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

Comment: No, it's asking to find something, which is also on the list.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't look like it.

Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1711) where someone's requesting it be added:

> There are already Font Awesome icons for HTML5 and CSS3, so one for JS would be logical. Something based on the community JavaScript logo would be awesome. Maybe an alt for the icon would be the specific use case logo from the repository mentioned above to go better with the existing HTML5 and CSS3 icons.

Someone in the comments noted that:

> The Font Awesome team said there will be a JS icon and other icons for other frameworks and languages in Font Awesome 5

In the mean time you might want to take a look at font-mfizz, an extension of font awesome. They do have a [javascript icon](http://fizzed.com/oss/font-mfizz/icon-javascript)

[image: js]